# Soccer leagues/teams/players API

Tags: data-request, api, sports

I wanted to know if anyone knows of a website that provides free information related to various soccer leagues.  I am creating a C# application. I'm interested in the following:

- table each league
- information on the players of the teams
- information teams
- Any other values that provides the site

Currently I draw these data with a parser on a website, but I would like to speed things up, leaning to the databases that are possibly free, but I am also willing to pay a small amount for the data.

Answer (score 6):

[**Football data**](http://www.football-data.co.uk/data.php) is a page with free statistics in .csv with a large data about matches, beats, results, players and other interesting facts.

Another very common used by journalists (a friend who is in the business pointed) is the [**Wikipedia of Soccer**](http://es.soccerwiki.org/wiki.php), which you download in .xml only. This page is also free.

Answer (score 5):

[Football-data API](http://api.football-data.org/index)

provide football data of all major european leagues in a machine-readable way like fixtures, teams, players, results and more. All this information is provided via an easy-to-use RESTful API in JSON (only) representation

Answer (score 1):

I've started to collect a list of football - that is, soccer in the U.S.A. ;-) - datasets, guides, etc. in the [Awesome Football List @ Planet Open Data](https://github.com/planetopendata/awesome-football). Cheers.

Comment: how many championships are available?

Answer (score 0):

Try fantasysportnet - http://fantasysportnet.com/data/home.jsp

They cover the major European football leagues … EPL, Bundesliga, Spanish league, Serie A, and provide stats through a simple API.

Answer (score 0):

The best website I know is [TranferMarkt](http://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/) (it is German but also has a proper English version).

It has all the data available on players throughout their football career. The thing you are probably interested most is called "Performance data" on player's profile pages. For example, [Robin van Persie's performance](http://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/robin-van-persie/leistungsdatendetails/spieler/4380).

I'm not sure how to parse the data properly though, I mean not just look up every player one by one. May be you'll find out how to optimize the data collection.

---

Also, there is an amazing collection of soccer data published openly at Kaggle -- [European Soccer Database](https://www.kaggle.com/hugomathien/soccer).
Make sure you check the diverse examples of analysis of this dataset -- the so called [kernels](https://www.kaggle.com/hugomathien/soccer/kernels).

From the data source description:

> What you get:
>
> - +25,000 matches
> - +10,000 players 11 European Countries with their lead championship
> - Seasons 2008 to 2016
> - Players and Teams' attributes* sourced from    EA Sports' FIFA video    game series, including the weekly updates
> - Team lineup with squad formation (X, Y coordinates)
> - Betting odds from up to 10 providers
> - Detailed match events (goal types,    possession, corner, cross,    fouls, cards etc...) for +10,000 matches

Answer (score 0):

There is a free API by ScoreBat that provides embed codes for goals & video highlights in real time - so I guess many of you guys developing soccer apps and websites will find it useful

https://www.scorebat.com/video-api/